# ld:library not found for -lXext but -lX11 can be found

Tags: macos, x11

I am trying to install ns2 to my Mac (Mountain Lion 10.8.4).  But I keep getting the error:

```
ld :library not found for -lX11.
```

The full gcc command is :

```
gcc -Os -pipe      -prebind -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-search_paths_first tkAppInit.o -L/Users/ww/ns-allinone-2.34/tk8.4.18/unix -ltk8.4 \
    -L/Users/ww/ns-allinone-2.34/tcl8.4.18/unix -ltcl8.4  -framework CoreFoundation -lX11   -sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist Wish-Info.plist  -o wish
```

I searched the internet and I was told that I need to install XQuartz. So I installed XQuartz and set the environment path to be like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/ww/ns-allinone-2.34/otcl-1.13:/usr/X11R6/lib:/Users/ww/ns-allinone-2.34/lib
```

But still nothing changes after I did the settings. Is there anything else that I can do here?

Comment: Alright... now some updates, turns out that approach is not working, so I use export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/X11R6/lib, this time it can find X11, but it could not find Xext... I can see that the libXext.dylib is right there, but it does not work!!!! Dizzy and angry!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set up DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. I had a similar problem with some MATLAB dyld's and made it work by something like (put it in .profile or just type the command in terminal)

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/library
```

OS X is different from Linux in this respect, it is a lot more painful to use non-standard shared libraries, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not working most of the time.